# Get short followers count without rounding up in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, social-media

I want to short a precise number of followers and display it in a nice way like the social platforms. The problem is that my code is rounding up the last digit.

```
function getShortFollowers(num){

 function intlFormat(num){
   return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.round(num*10)/10);
 }

 if(num >= 1000000)
   return intlFormat(num/1000000)+'M';
 if(num >= 1000)
   return intlFormat(num/1000)+'k';
 return intlFormat(num);
}

// Result
console.log(getShortFollowers(28551) // output: 28.6 

// Wanted result
console.log(getShortFollowers(28551) // output: 28.5
```

If I divide Math.round with 100 instead of 10 I prevent the rounding up but get two digit decimal, which is unwanted.

Comment: Use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```js
function getShortFollowers(num){

 function intlFormat(num){
   return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.floor(num*10)/10);
 }

 if(num >= 1000000)
   return intlFormat(num/1000000)+'M';
 if(num >= 1000)
   return intlFormat(num/1000)+'k';
 return intlFormat(num);
}

// Result
console.log(getShortFollowers(28551)) // output: 28.5k
```